# Is it possible to remove milliseconds from TO_TIMESTAMP function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query

```
SELECT ORDER_DATE, MIN(TO_TIMESTAMP(START_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS:AM'))
```

which gives me this output

```
16-AUG-19 08.09.51.000000000 AM
```

its fine except for .000000000 part. I dont need that part, and im not sure how its coming up if its HH:MI:SS format

this is for oracle sql developer.

Comment: What data type is `START_TIME`?

Comment: hey man its varchar2(30)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just convert to a `date`?  That datatype doesn't have fractions of a second:

```
SELECT ORDER_DATE, MIN(TO_DATE(START_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS:AM'))
```

Comment: So its a varchar(2) and when I convert it to date and output it it jsut shows the date the issue I just need time

this is the output of that

16-AUG-19

Comment: @WinterOne . . . The time is there.  You can format the result as a string using `to_char()` or change your tool's parameters to see the full time.

Answer (score -1):

Output `16-AUG-19 08.09.51.000000000 AM` is defined by your session parameter `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`. Change it to

```
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'dd-MON-RR HH:MI:SS AM';
```

Then milliseconds will not be displayed - however, they are still part of the actual value.

Note, you convert to a `TIMESTAMP` thus `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` applies, neither  `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` nor `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: If you don't want fraction of a second then don't use a timestamp use a date